# Date and time parameter In msrs report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Hi I am looking to set up my report so the start date will always be say `'14-09-2011 00:00:00'`
And the end date will always be `'14-09-2011 23:59:59'` Or in other words Start date will be 00:00 and end date will be `23:59` for what ever days I select.

At the moment my parameters are

```
Startdate: =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today())

End Date: =today()
```

Comment: How does **this** get migrated to DBA?  This is purely a programming question.

Comment: @Yuck SSRS/SSAS/BI stuff is all on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about setting the time component.  Just write your query like this instead:

```
WHERE SomeColumn >= @StartDate
  AND SomeColumn < DATEADD(Day, 1, @EndDate)
```

You have `@EndDate = Today()` which by default does not have a time component (or rather it's already `00:00:00`).  Adding a whole day to that gets you *tomorrow at midnight*.  So the query above asks for any data on or after `@StartDate` but no later than *tomorrow at midnight*.

If you're querying a SQL 2K8+ instance you can further do this to be sure you're not erroneously using a time component:

```
WHERE SomeColumn >= CONVERT(Date, @StartDate)
  AND SomeColumn < CONVERT(Date, DATEADD(Day, 1, @EndDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the SQL approach since this is the obvious answer but its not clear you are even using that...

You've got your start date ie 00:00:00 since

> =Today() 'returns date only

so perhaps add a day and remove a second to get 23:59:59

> =DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, -1, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Today()))

Comment: You can lose the last second of the day doing this if your data has milliseconds.